# convert byte to KB, MB, GB, TB, ... with RX in android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

For example I have this value `5465881`, How can I convert this `byte` to  KB, MB, GB, TB, ... with `RX` in android?

Comment: How is that related to RX?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize` or a similar method in the Formatter class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter.html#formatFileSize(android.content.Context,%20long)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method

```
public static String formatSize(long size) {
    if (size <= 0) return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[]{"B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + units[digitGroups];
}


formatSize(5465881) returns -> 5.2MB
```

Comment: not a safe function! Crashlytics reported: `Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=5; index=319302040`